# How do I redirect the user back to the page he comes from using vue-router middleware?

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following created the following codes that works as middlewares to my vue components.

```
  Router.beforeEach(
  (to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forVisitors)) {
      if (Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        next({
          path: '/home'
        })
      } else next()
    } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forAuth)) {
      if (!Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        next({
          path: '/login'
        })
      } else next()
    } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forLog)) {
      if (Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        next({
          path: from()
        })
      }else if (!localStorage.getItem('validUser')) {
                next({
          path: '/login'
        })
            } else next()
    } else next()
  }
)
```

Most of the middlewares are working fine. but the `from()` is not working.
I also tried to do this as `from` but it is not still redirecting the user back to the page he came from.

Comment: `path: from.path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you console.log `from` you get the following

```
Object {name: null, meta: Object, path: "/", hash: "", query: Object…}
fullPath
:
"/"
hash
:
""
matched
:
Array(0)
meta
:
Object
name
:
null
params
:
Object
path
:
"/"
query
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
```

You can see that from is not a `string` but an object. Instead, use the `path` attribute of the object like in the sample below

```
else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forLog)) {
   if (Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log(from);
    next({
       path: from.path
    })
```